# WiX Burn Bootstrapper - is it possible to detect non-interactive mode?

Tags: wix, burn, eula

I wish to add a bal:condition to my WiX Boostrapper project to only allow it to continue in *quiet* mode if the user has specified "AcceptEula=1" on the command line.

However, if the installer is run interactively, there is already a checkbox that must be ticked to continue, so that is fine and I don't want the user to have to enter this parameter.

Therefore, I would like to do something like:

```
<Variable Name="AcceptEula" Value="0" Type="numeric" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
<bal:Condition Message="You must accept the EULA">(<TEST FOR QUIET MODE>) AND (AccepEula=1)</bal:Condition>
```

Does anyone know if this possible, or have any suggestions for alternatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible today without writing code, there is already a feature request for this at http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3825/.

Comment: Thank you Sean.... when you say writing code, is this as simple as writing a little managed "plugin" and hooking it into the Bootstrap workflow, or is this a case of modifying the source code of the Bootstrap workflow - the former I could image doing, the latter sounds like a lot of hassle :)